# UIView subview is not autorotating or auto-sizing for iPad

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, subview

In my iPhone app, I have a UIViewController with two subviews: a main UIView (let's call it mainView), and a secondary UIView (let's call it secondView), which is usually hidden but is sometimes shown (e.g. user settings). In my UIViewController, self.view is set to mainView. When the user switches to the subview, I call `[self.view addSubview:secondView]` and when the user switches back to the main UIView, I call `[secondView removeFromSuperview]`.

There are two issues which I am dealing with at present:

1. When the user rotates the iPhone or iPad, the main UIView (mainView) autorotates properly and all of its UI items follow its autoresize rules which I have set up in Interface Builder. However, when the secondary UIView (secondView) is displayed, and the iPhone or iPad is rotated, the secondView & all of its UI items do not follow their autoresize rules. I have found that when I set `self.view = secondView`, and then rotate the device, the view rotates properly.
2. In the iPad specifically, when I pull up the secondView using `[self.view addSubview:secondView]`, it is not resized to fill the full screen just as the main UIView has been resized for the iPad version. So I end up with a screen that displays the mainView UIView in the background, and the secondView UIView in the top-left corner without taking up the whole screen.

My instinct tells me that these two issues are related to one another. Has anyone else experienced these kinds of issues with secondary UIViews which they add to their UIViewControllers using `addSubview:`?

Comment: I'm having a similar experience on the iPhone with ios6. I have a usually hidden subview that just insists on being oriented to portrait even when everything else is oriented to landscape. It's like it just never bothered to understand that it is part of the view hierarchy below views all of which have rotated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `addSubview`,

```
[secondView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
```

Not very elegant. But it worked for me:

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved the size issue by setting the content mode of the view.

```
Exp:[_yourView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: You should format your code between ``` or with 4 spaces in front of code. There is a button that help formatting code.